# Outlook change control messes up formatting in HTML

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

Whenever I edit an email message in Outlook 2003 sent in HTML format (such as forwarding a message and copying a piece which I want to change, adding comments for example), Outlook automatically changes the font and other formatting options to make the changes stand out. It looks terrible, and I can't seem to change the font, color etc explicitly.

Does anyone know how to fix this annoying behaviour? Is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling HTML editing?  Maybe go RTF for a little while?